# C++ Curl adding and sending cookies

Tags: c++, http, post, cookies

I've been trying to write a program that sends post data and COOKIES . The Cookie adding part seems not to add cookies properly...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
  struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
  static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);


   /* Fill in the nick field */ 
   curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "nick",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "nichnameofxxx",
               CURLFORM_END);

   /* Fill in the pass field */ 
   curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "pass",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "passwordofxxx",
               CURLFORM_END);

   /* Other fields like ID */ 
   curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "ProfileID",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "77820",
               CURLFORM_END);

  /* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */ 
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
               CURLFORM_END);


  curl = curl_easy_init();
  /* initalize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
     wanted */ 

  headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);

  //Cookies here... it's a part of the Header
  headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Cookie: name=xxx; name2=xxx");

  if(curl) 
  {

     // what URL that receives this POST

     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mything.org/index.php?id=log2");

     if ((argc == 2) && (!strcmp(argv[1], "noexpectheader")))
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
     res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
     curl_formfree(formpost);
     curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

ANY help is welcome!

Comment: By not adding cookies properly, what do you mean with that? What happens? Is there an error while building? An error while running? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: I have a test website where You can only change the topic if you have a correct COOKIE. I tested the website and it catches the cookie just fine. So the only thing that's wrong is the program code...

Comment: And why do you assume your browser saves the cookies to the same place libcurl does?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start "cookie engine" first, this is done with:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
```

Instead of setting HTTP header explicitly, set cookies with CURLOPT_COOKIE:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "name=xxx; name2=xxx;");
```

Comment: I have used it, and i am very much sure that the second statement is enough to start the cookie engine and send the cookies.

Comment: You're Right, abhishek chandel .